# how to update the default value of textbox in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

expected output:
am working on admin module where if click a user i get all his details those value gets binded in the textbox(till here it working fine) using onChange i edit one value and click edit it needs to pass the values to the DB

what am getting is : 
the values which i dont change goes to api as null the value which i change are recived to the api.
any solutions for this thanks in advance.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import {toast} from 'react-toastify'

class ViewUserById extends Component {
    constructor(props) {  
        super(props);
        this.state = {
             Users:this.props.location.state,
        }
        console.log('byid',this.state.Users);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }
    onChange = (event) =>{
        const Users = this.state.Users;
        Users[event.target.name]= event.target.value;
        this.setState({
            Users :Users
        })
       console.log(this.state.Users);
    }

    edit =()=>{
        const headers ={
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        }
        debugger
        axios.post('https://localhost:/api/Updateuser',this.state.Users,{
            headers:headers
        })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
            if(res.data === 1){
                toast.success('records updated',{position : toast.POSITION.TOP_RIGHT,autoClose : 4000})
            }
            else{
                toast.error('records not updated,try again',{position : toast.POSITION.TOP_RIGHT,autoClose : 4000})
            }
        })
        .catch(Error =>{
            console.log(Error);
        })

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={()=>{this.props.history.push('/ViewUser')}}>back</button> <br/><br/>
            <div>
              {

                this.state.Users ?
                this.state.Users.UserbyId.map(Users => <div key={Users}><div>

               <input type="text"  defaultValue={Users.firstname}  value={this.state.Users.UserbyId.firstname} name="firstname"  onChange={this.onChange} className="form-control form-control-sm"/> <br/>
               <input type="text"  defaultValue={Users.lastname}  value={this.state.Users.UserbyId.lastname} name="lastname"  onChange={this.onChange}  className="form-control form-control-sm"/> <br/>
               <input type="text"  defaultValue={Users.mobileNumber}  value={this.state.Users.UserbyId.mobileNumber} name="mobileNumber"  onChange={this.onChange}  className="form-control form-control-sm"/> <br/>
               <input type="text"  defaultValue={Users.aadharNumber} value={this.state.Users.UserbyId.aadharNumber} name="aadharNumber"  onChange={this.onChange}  className="form-control form-control-sm"/><br/>
               <input type="text" defaultValue={Users.emailId} value={this.state.Users.UserbyId.emailId} name="emailId"  onChange={this.onChange}  className="form-control form-control-sm"/><br/>
               <input type="text"  defaultValue={Users.address} value={this.state.Users.UserbyId.address} name="address"  onChange={this.onChange}  className="form-control form-control-sm"/><br/>
                <input type="text"  defaultValue={Users.city}  value={this.state.Users.UserbyId.city}  name="city"  onChange={this.onChange}  className="form-control form-control-sm"/><br/>
                <input type="text"  defaultValue={Users.pincode}  value={this.state.Users.UserbyId.pincode} name="pincode"  onChange={this.onChange}  className="form-control form-control-sm"/><br/>
                <br>
                </br>
                <button onClick={this.edit}>Edit</button>

                </div></div>) : null
              }    
            </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ViewUserById
```

Comment: Afaik, `defaultValue` are only assigned when the component mounts, and will not be updated. Because the reason they are there is for uncontrolled inputs, which means React doesn't need to handle their updates. If you unmount the components, and mount it again, it should be using the new value as the `defaultValue`.

Comment: @Afaik sry can you plz brief it or give any solutions for this am stuck up here am new to react